# Texting/phone calls greetings and business

Tags: halacha, shacharis-morning-prayer, transactions, business, phone

Is one allowed to text/call someone else before shacharit to greet them or do business? Would it be different from regular speech or no? And this is in a case without financial loss to be clear.

Sources would be very appreciated please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One should not go to someone to greet him before morning prayers**, as it shows this person is more important than God, although one can greet someone when meeting him (some say it is best not to use the word "Shalom" since it is one of God's name). See [SA OC 89:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.89.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and Peninei Halacha [here](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/02-12-01/). Presumably calling someone on purpose is the same as going to see them.

Regarding engaging in business before prayer, Peninei Halacha [puts it best](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/02-12-02/)

> From the time of *amud hashachar*, **it is prohibited to deal with one’s
> work before praying**. This is because holy matters precede secular
> matters and the respect of Heaven precedes the needs of people.
> Therefore, it is necessary to first thank Hashem in prayer, and only
> afterwards deal with one’s own needs.

So net net you should not call someone before prayers simply to greet them or do business, although you can call someone socially. If you are calling for a mitzva then it is permitted (see sources above).

Comment: What's the difference between calling someone to greet them and calling them socially?

Comment: Halacha speaks of greeting someone (saying shalom to him), not calling socially

Comment: They're the same thing. להקדים לפתח חבירו ליתן לו שלום means a social visit.